# PHP and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some text I am parsing like this:

> Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
>   text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
>   Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
>   text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
>   Some text. Some text. Some text.
>   [attachment=0]Winter.jpg[/attachment]Some
>   text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
>   Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
>   text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
>   Some text.

I want to match and remove any instance of text like this from the string:

```
[attachment=0]Winter.jpg[/attachment]
```

where Winter.jpg can be any text.

However, I am getting some PHP Notices. I used regexpal.com to construct this, which works there but uses a Javascript REGEX function:

```
\[attachment=.*?].*\[/attachment]
```

When I run this code:

```
$pm_row['message_text'] = preg_replace('\[attachment=.*?\].*\[/attachment\]', '', $pm_row['message_text']);
```

PHP complains with a notice:

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /mail_digests.php on line 841: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

So on a similar line of code, I delimit the pattern with a "/":

```
$post_row['post_text'] = preg_replace('/\[attachment=.*?].*\[/attachment]/', '', $post_row['post_text']);
```

But this generates the following:

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /mail_digests.php on line 957: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'a'
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [escape every occurrence of the delimiter inside the pattern](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters):

> If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash. If the delimiter appears often inside the pattern, it is a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to increase readability.

So escape it:

```
'/\[attachment=.*?].*\[\/attachment]/'
                       ^
```

By the way: Currently the [quantifier](http://php.net/regexp.reference.repetition) in `.*` is greedy, that means it will match as much as possible. You might want to change it to an ungreedy variant using `?` like you did before.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the problem. The OP will also need to make the `.*` ungreedy (`.*?`) if there might be more than one attachment in the parsed text.

Comment: Thanks. Regular expressions are a challenge!

Comment: OK, apparently my expression needs some refinement. How I have:    $pm_row['message_text'] = preg_replace('/\[attachment=.*?].*?\[\/attachment]/', '', $pm_row['message_text']);
but it does not match my string of winter.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need a delimeter, and you need to **escape** it if you're actually using it in your expression (i.e.: `[/attachment]` has a `/` in it). Escape it or change your delimiter (`#` for example).

Comment: It's hard to see but the / is escaped: '/[attachment=.*?].*?[\/attachment]/'. Changing to #\[attachment=.*?].*?\[\/attachment]# did not solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve this. My test data in the example was bad, so I was trying to match an invalid pattern.